# Is ternary operator interpreted as I intended?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
    public class FileStorage
    {

        private static FileStorage _instance;
        public static FileStorage instance
        {
            get
            {
                return (_instance != null) ? _instance : _instance = new FileStorage();
            }
        }

        //public string GetAddress...

    }
```

can i use that piece of code for a simple singleton solution? the code will execute on single thread.

Does the return, return a new FileStorage()?
what does exactly be returned here?

```
var foo = (bee = new[]{/*immagination...*/})
```

will foo be a boolean value? or effectively it's a reference to bee?

Comment: Yes, you can use this. It's easier to write `public static FileStorage instance => _instance ??= new FileStorage()` though. Why not see what data type `foo` is in your example?

Comment: Thx canton7, i'm rather far to the concept of c#, i'm rather new with debugging either, and I'm running vs code couse here i started, here we are, with you faster than my trial and error :'D

Comment: Use e.g. https://sharplab.io to test things without having to open anything at all. We are not here so that you can be lazy: you're expected to put effort into solving your problems yourself

Comment: "simple singleton solution"? [No](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton).

Comment: Downvote for "does not show research effort", since the question is easily testable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this would work as you intended. However, even if you are working with a single-threaded application, keep in mind that this method is not thread-safe.

Still, to avoid going on a bug hunt when you need to use threads in your app, it is usually better to ensure thread safety precautionarily.

For example:

```
public class FileStorage
{
    private static readonly object _singletonLock = new object();
    private static FileStorage _instance = null;
    public static FileStorage Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_singletonLock)
            {
                return _instance ??= new FileStorage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code snippet makes use of the `??=` operator (assign if null) and also encapsulates the getter method of the `Instance` property in a `lock`-statement to ensure thread safety.
`??=` is much more compact and easier to read and has the same effect as your ternary operator.

Comment: didn't know about Assign if null operator, really nice to have it there explained thanks, I asked the question couse i really don't get the magic ~ wizardry, about `()? true : b = false` and why shoud it work at a lower compute level